# HtmlHelper and htmlAttributes help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html

I'm fairly new to MVC 3 and am using the Razor view engine. I'm using the Html.Hidden extension method to output input elements of type hidden. What I woudl also like to do is add a custom attribute to hold a dynamic value. I was under the impression in HTML5 wee could write custom html element attributes that are prefixed with 'data-'. I'm trying to do something like below;

`@Html.Hidden("hdnID", mymodel.somevalue, new { data-uniqueid = mymodel.somevalue })`

hoping to render;

`<input type="hidden" value="mymodel.somevalue" data-uniqueid="mymodel.somevalue"/>`

The htmlAttributes part (*new { data-uniqueid = mymodel.somevalue }*) is giving the error,

"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access".

Can I add user-defined attribute to html elements using the HtmlHelper classes?

Regards,

Comment: Don't you need: new { data-uniqueid = @mymodel.somevalue } you are missing a @ I think.

Comment: Mmm... no, still the same error I'm affraid.

Comment: Even if I declare new {data-uniqueid = "somevalue" } explicitly, I still get the error. Perhaps suggesting the attribute is not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I was being silly. You can't have '-' in the anon type declaration:

`data-uniqueid = ...`it must be

`datauniqueid = ....`

In that case, your best best is to write out the hidden input by hand:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@mymodel.somevalue" data-uniqueid="@mymodel.somevalue"/>
```

Comment: What strange behaviour, bearing in mind the html5 specifications! Anyway, that's done it. It's not important that I include the hyphen, I was just trying to conform to the standard! Many thanks.

Comment: To the downvoter, please could you explain why you did it please. It would help a lot, since I could correct any mistakes which you think deserved a downvote.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain. "The best" and "must" in your post is just wrong. The answer from @mccow002 should be the one marked as the correct answer

Comment: Wow, looking at my answer, it makes no sense to me now! lol. You're right, @mccow002 answer is correct.

Comment: See mccow002's answer below.

Comment: @JamesHaug I can't delete my answer as it's been accepted. Plus, as my comment above suggests, I'm fully aware that mccow002's answer is correct. It's up to the OP to update the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

Use:

```
@Html.Hidden("hdnID", mymodel.somevalue, new { @data_uniqueid = mymodel.somevalue })
```

The underscore gets automatically converted to a dash.

Comment: +1 As I've since learned, correctly, about using the underscore character like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can step around the member validation by constructing a dictionary object. As follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {
        "data-call-results-target", "#search-results-area" 
    },
    {
        "data-action-path", "/Controler/Method"
    }
})
```